# Vue.js router init works with router.map not with the Router constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In my app, I use the vue-router. Routes work when I pass them to the router with router.map({}), but they don't work when I pass them in the constructor. Any idea why this is?

```
// works:
const router = new VueRouter() 
router.map({
    '/user' : {
        component : User,
        subRoutes : {}
    }
})

// does not work:
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes : [
        {
            path : '/user',
            component : User,
            children : []
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Oh what Vue router version you are using ? First (working) one is for old vue router I think `0.9.x` version and works only with Vue 1.Second one is new Vue router version which works only with Vue 2.

Comment: So simple... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there are 2 versions of Vue Router.

1st - Vue Router `0.7.x` which only works with VueJS `1.x.x` version.The working example you posted is Vue Router `0.7.x` version syntax, so probably you are running VueJS `1.x.x` on your app.

2nd - Vue Router `2.x` which only works with VueJS `2.x.x`.The second non-working examplte is Vue Router `2.x` version syntax.

So make sure what VueJS version you are running, and then apply correct Vue Router Version, and use correct syntax.

Docs for Vue Router `2.x.x` - https://router.vuejs.org/en/
Docs for Vue Router `0.7.x` - https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/tree/1.0/docs/en